# How can I fetch database rows in Pojo without using JOOQ code generation?

Tags: java, pojo, jooq

I'm trying to use JOOQ without code generation. I have a dao class that looks like this

```
public class FilesDao { 
public List<FilePojo> getAllFiles() {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceFactory.getTestiDataSource();
    List<FilePojo> filePojos = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.MARIADB);
        filePojos = create.select(field("tiedosto.id"), field("tiedosto.nimi"), field("tiedosto.koko_tavua"),
                field("tiedosto.sisalto"), field("tiedosto.hlo_id"))
                .from(table("tiedosto"))
                .where(field("minioupload").eq((byte) 0))
                .fetch().into(FilePojo.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filePojos;
   }
}
```

and a Pojo class that looks like this

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name="tiedosto")
public class FilePojo {

@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "hlo_id")
private Integer customerId;

@Column(name = "koko_tavua")
private Integer fileSize;

@Column(name = "nimi")
private String fileName;

@Column(name = "sisalto")
private byte[] content;}
//Getters setters omitted
```

When I try to read from the table using a main method like this

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FilesDao mydao = new FilesDao();
    List<FilePojo> myList = mydao.getAllFiles();
    for (FilePojo filePojo : myList) {
        System.out.println("==========================================" + "\n" +
                filePojo.getId() + " " +
                filePojo.getCustomerId() + " " +
                filePojo.getFileName() + " " +
                filePojo.getFileSize() + " " +
                filePojo.getContent() + " " +
                "==========================================");
    }
  }
}
```

The output is as follows
[image]

I can see that the SQL query is running fine and listing all the matched rows, but pojo is returning null values. What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please point me to the right direction? I'd really appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm undecided whether this is a [bug or a feature](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7995). You're using the [plain SQL templating API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) when you should probably be using the [identifier building API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/). When you write

```java
field("tiedosto.id")
```

Then, jOOQ (possibly erroneously) thinks that your column is named `` `tiedosto.id` ``, with a period in the name. When it should really be qualified as `` `tiedosto`.`id` ``. There are a few possible fixes:

#### Keep using the plain SQL templating API

But then, don't qualify the name:

```java
field("id")
```

#### Use the identifier building API

```java
field(name("tiedosto", "id"))
```

#### Use the code generator

This should always be your preferred option, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Removing table name did the trick. I usually and mostly prefer code generator, I was just trying to play around a little with jooq.